# UITextView get and lost focus events

Tags: iphone

How can I get event when my UITextView get and lost focus? I have not found such as events. (UITextView is not editable)

Comment: if your `UITextView` is not editable, it never gets the "focus" (become first responder), therefore it cannot lose what it has not. so, can you clarify you question, please?

Answer (score 0):

Use override touchesBegan in your code

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([touch view]==textviewtofocus)
    {
        // textviewtofocus get focus
    }
else 
// textviewtofocus lost focus

}
```

Comment: @revolutionkpi, did u get it?

Comment: I added this method but it is never called